# Qt. Как сделать анимацию из двух+ .png файлов

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь понять, как проще и с меньшими затратами по ресурсам организовать анимацию из нескольких *png*-файлов.

Мне надо, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу у меня происходила поочередная смена картинок. Например:

```
player1.png , player2.png, player3.png
```

Сейчас я использую `setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/player/res/player1.png"));` для отображения статической картинки "player1.png"

и метод `void Player::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)` для её перемещения.

Сейчас в голову приходит две мысли:

1. `QPropertyAnimation`, но не смог найти информации с примером, как можно прописать несколько *.png файлов и чередовать их по очереди;
2. использовать сигналы, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку по очереди вызывались и удалялись картинки.

Если можете, то подскажите решения. Хорошо если будут какие-нибудь примеры.

Answer (score 1):

`QPropertyAnimation` поддерживает автоматическую смену значений только для свойств виджетов (объектов), приведённых в списке на странице к описанию класса `QVariantAnimation`. Состав списка включает: `Int`, `UInt`, `Double`, `Float`, `QLine`, `QLineF`, `QPoint`, `QPointF`, `QSize`, `QSizeF`, `QRect`, `QRectF` и `QColor`. Таким образом, свойство, использующее `QPixmap` в качестве типа данных, не может быть задействовано в анимации стандартным образом.

В рассматриваемой ситуации возможно использовать машину состояний `QStateMachine`. Далее, тело произвольного метода:

```
//! Некий виджет-метка, на котором будем рисовать.
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);

QStringList fnames;
fnames.append(QLatin1String(":/images/player/res/player1.png"));
fnames.append(QLatin1String(":/images/player/res/player2.png"));
fnames.append(QLatin1String(":/images/player/res/player3.png"));

QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine(this);

connect(machine, &QStateMachine::stopped
    , machine, &QStateMachine::deleteLater);
connect(machine, &QStateMachine::finished
    , machine, &QStateMachine::deleteLater);

QTimer *timer = new QTimer(machine);
timer->setInterval(1000);
timer->setSingleShot(true);

QList<QAbstractState*> states;
foreach(const QString &fname, fnames) {
    QState *state = new QState(machine);
    state->assignProperty(label, "pixmap", QPixmap(fname));
    connect(state, &QState::entered, timer, &QTimer::start);
    states.append(state);
}

states.append(new QFinalState(machine));

QListIterator<QAbstractState*> itr(states);
if(itr.hasNext()) itr.next();

while(itr.hasNext()) {
    QState *state = qobject_cast<QState*>(itr.peekPrevious());
    state->addTransition(timer, &QTimer::timeout, itr.next());
}

machine->setInitialState(states.first());

QMetaObject::invokeMethod(machine, "start", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит использовать ивенты для этого.

напишите слот, который будет менять картинки.
Соедините clicked() с этим слотом. Вот и все.

FSM  в этом случае по моему тоже как из пушки по воробям.

```
///////header
private: QLabel _picture;

private slots: void changeImage();

////////source
// add image file names
_picture->setProperty("myImageList", QStringList()<<"image1.png"<<"image1.png");
//Connect button to slot
connect(myButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(changeImage()) );

void MyClass::changeImage()
{
  QStringList tmpimglist = _picture->property("myImageList").toStringList();
  int currentImage = _picture->property("myImageListCurrentImage").toInt();
  if ( currentImage >=0 && currentImage <tmpimglist.size() )
    picture->setPixmap(QPixmap(tmpimglist.at(currentImage)));

  currentImage++;
  if ( currentImage>= tmpimglist.size())
    currentImage=0;
  _picture->setProperty("myImageListCurrentImage", currentImage);
}
```

Список файлов и актуальный индекс в списке конечно тоже можно определить членами класса.
Я просто хотел показать как можно использовать Qt-property чтоб не перегружать класс необязательными членами.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. 
У меня очень маленькие картинки. Я загрузил их в кэш
QPixmapCache и перебирал их через слот.